# In php, mysql how to run a loop only if record exist

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I have a php script which has series of calculations and FORM RELOADS based on user Selection/Inputs, I need to run these only IF a record ADDITION is done to the table and not on FORM RELOADS, how to run a loop with this condition.

**my PARTIAL php script bill-detail.php:**
HOPE THIS WOULD SUFFICE:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Cash Bill Detail</title>


<script language="javascript">

function reload(form)
{
document.location.href = 'bill-detail.php'
}



function showecr(str)
{

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","billecr.php?q1=" + str,false);
xmlhttp.send();
 }

</script>


</head>
<body>

<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","svga","a!@#");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("svga", $con);

$user = $_SESSION['user'];

//<!--------------VALIDATIONS ------------------->

echo "<form name='form1'>";
echo "ECR: <input type='text' size='10' maxlength='10' name='ecrn'     onchange=\"showecr(this.value);\"><br>";
echo "Product Type";
echo "<select name='product' onchange=\"reload(this.form);\">>";
echo "<option value='Gas'>Gas</option>";
echo "<option value='Others'>Others</option>";
echo "</select>";
echo "</form>";


//---As per user inputs copying value to variables---------------------
$hdr=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM BILLHDR_draft WHERE usr='$user'");
$hdr2=mysql_fetch_assoc($hdr);
$numrows=mysql_num_rows($hdr);

if ($numrows>0)

{
$cust_code=$hdr2['Ac_code'];
$product=$hdr2['prod_desc'];

//--Searching BILL DETAILS TABLE as per the user inputs from BILL HEADER Table------
$recs=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM BILLDTLS WHERE Ac_code='$cust_code' AND     Prod_desc='$product'");
while ($rec2=mysql_fetch_assoc($recs))
{
mysql_query("INSERT INTO DEMURAGE (DC_No, DC_date, Ac_code, Product_Desc) VALUES ('$rec2[dc]', '$rec2[dcdate]', '$rec2[accode]', '$rec2[product]'");
}

}

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Pro tip: You need to run something IF a condition is true.  PHP has an `IF` keyword.  If you still can't figure out a solution you might want to look at PHP's manual.

Comment: Show your code and the part where the problem is.

Comment: @GordonM You are right IF condition would suffice, but the problem is the if condition will always be true if I am using like IF (num_rows>0){ my calculations }, what i need is this loop should work only once when a record is added and not for every FORM RELOADS.

Comment: You need to show the code you have and clarify what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Juhana  Pl check the code added !

Answer (score 0):

You can add a boolean variable before the loop that you can use to track on whether a record has been added already. The following code is largely concept being that you didn't provide much of an example of code yourself, but hopefully you get the idea.

```
// Set to false initially
$recordAdded = FALSE;

if( $num_rows > 0 && $recordAdded == FALSE )
{
   // Code to execute

   // Set value to to TRUE after initial successful execution
   $recordAdded = TRUE;
}
```

Comment: The above would work if there is no FORM RELOAD, I have pasted my partial php SCRIPT, if i do as per your example, everytime the form reloads $recordAdded will be false and $num_rows will be greater than 0 and loop works.

Comment: You could use a cookie or session to store the value of the boolean variable, or just simply set a cookie or start a session the first time through and then on reload check if cookie or session exists and if so ignore loop.

Comment: Is there any example for this on the web ?

Comment: Sure is, lots of them. These should sort you out: [Cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp) and [Sessions](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp). You only need one or the other, not both.